# Can't change linux user password with php script

Tags: linux, user-management, php7

I have the following php script for password change:
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_error', true);

```
$cmd = 'sudo -u root sh -c \'/usr/bin/echo "username:pass" | sudo /usr/sbin/chpasswd 2>&1\'';
exec($cmd,$output,$return_val);
print_r($output);
echo $return_val;
?>
```

This script show error in browser:

```
pam_chauthtok() failed, error: [1] => Authentication token lock busy [2] => chpasswd
```

But the command

```
sudo -u root sh -c '/usr/bin/echo "username:pass" | sudo /usr/sbin/chpasswd 2>&1'
```

work fine.
Can please someone give me a tip, why I get in browser the error above?

Filesystem is in rw mode. Files /etc/{passwd,shadow} have a correct permissions

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you run PHP?

Comment: Php run with php-fpm

Comment: You... probably should not do this.

Comment: I know what you mean. Client needed a solution. I found the solution and warned about the upcoming problems with security

Comment: And the problem was exactly there, because strace showed that the filesystem is in read-only mode

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to comment out `ProtectSystem=full` in php-fpm.service unit:

```
# Mounts the /usr, /boot, and /etc directories read-only for processes invoked by this unit.
#ProtectSystem=full
```

Comment: You may change this to `true` instead, which will allow writing to `/etc` but still prohibit writing to the other named directories.

Answer (score 0):

Browser php runs using `www-data` user

Add permissions for `www-data` to use `sudo` through shell using `visudo` command and append this line

```
www-data   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Its' syntax is

```
user    hosts=(users:groups)    commands
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention here: I gave already sudo privileges. For testing I have the following line: nginx ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL. But that did not help.

Comment: The `sudo` access should be limited to only the commands that are needed.

Comment: Have you tried the same with www-data instead of nginx?

Comment: www-data user does not exist

Comment: Okay. Which OS are you using? Have you verified if <?php echo exec('whoami'); ?> on browser returns nginx?

Comment: OpenSUSE 15.2. Yes, exec(...whoami...ls....ping...cat...) work everything